# How can I prevent an app from leaving full screen mode when I move the cursor to another display?

Tags: multiple-monitors, flash, synergy

When I have dual displays set up, or when I am using Synergy to use one keyboard and mouse across two computers/screens, I can't seem to retain <kbd>F11</kbd> full screen mode for the top application when I mouse out of that screen. This applies to both the application and also to any Flash video that may be playing in full screen mode.

Is there any way to retain full screen mode and mouse out of the display?

Comment: Are you seeing this behaviour in multiple applications, or only with Flash?  I have noticed Flash's full screen mode behave a bit erratically, but other applications don't seem to share that behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this hack helps, but I've set up short-cuts using System >> Preferences >> Keyboard Short-cuts with: 
<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> for desktop 1,
 
<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> for desktop 2,
 
<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> for desktop 3,
 
<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> for desktop 4, etc...
as this allows me to shift between the desktops even when applications/programs are in full screen mode (<kbd>F11</kbd>).